# How can I show $\forall n\in\mathbb N[p|(k=\prod_{i}^{n}a_{i})\implies\exists_{i=1,...,n}:p|a_{i}]$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm being asked the following:

> Let $k$ denote a product of natural numbers $a_{i}$ such that $k=\prod_{i}^{n}a_{i}$ and $p$ be a prime number. Show that $$\forall n\in\mathbb N[p|k\implies\exists_{i=1,...,n}:p|a_{i}]$$

---

I know it's the generalization of Euclid's lemma, which is the case for two natural numbers $\{a_{i}\}_{0}^{1}$, but I have no idea on how to get started on this (induction?). I would appreciate it if someone took the time to get me started with a hint or idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep, try induction by $n$

Comment: Your comments [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2499811/are-there-limits-whose-convergence-divergence-is-undecidable?noredirect=1#comment5163472_2499811) are nonsense. And see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems

Comment: @reuns Your comment was nonsense, i.e sequences and series are the same thing... It's obvious they're not, for a "series" is an operation on a sequence, and sequence is just an ordered collection of numbers. I know what the theorem says, but your argument is non sequitur.

Comment: @IVLIVSCÆSAR By definition a series is the limit of the sequence of its partial sums. Limits of sequences and series are exactly the same thing. Obviously you don't know what means undecidable since you claimed everything is decidable.

Comment: @reuns Undecidability and unprovability are not the same thing. Also, I didn't say *everything*. I posted an answer below in regards to this.

Comment: @IVLIVSCÆSAR Don't post it in this unrelated question. Any arithmetic problem can be put in a form "does this sequence converge", so when you say for every sequence its convergence is decidable it is the same as every arithmetic problem is decidable, which is not the case for any consistent axiomatic theory of arithmetic you choose. By definition $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \lim_{N \to \infty} A_N$ where $A_N =\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$ and $\lim_{N \to \infty} A_N = \sum_{n=1}^\infty (A_n-A_{n-1})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S(n)$ be the statement $\forall a_1,..., a_n\;(p|\prod_{i=1}^na_i\implies \exists i\leq n\;(p|a_i)).$

$S(1)$ is (trivially) true.

$S(2)$ is Euclid's lemma, which we assume to have been proven.

Suppose $n\geq 2$ and $S(n)$ is true. If $p|\prod_{i=1}^{n+1}a_i$ let $a'_1=\prod_{i=1}^na_i$ and $a'_2=a_{n+1}.$

Then $p|a'_1a'_2$. By $S(2)$ we have $(p|a'_1 \lor p|a'_2=a_{n+1}.)$ Now if $p|a'_1$ then $\exists i\leq n\;(p|a_i)$ by $S(n).$

So $(\exists i\leq n\;(p|a_i))\lor (p|a_{n+1}),$ which is equivalent to $\exists i\leq n+1\;(p|a_i).$

Therefore for $n\geq 2$ we have $S(n)\implies S(n+1).$

Answer (score 0):

I would start by contradiction, assuming that left side of implication is true (p|k) and right is false (there is no such ai). Induction is maybe even better idea, hint: you can interpret product of ai as: a1 times product of rest of ai (without a1)

Answer (score 0):

Let $(a_{n})_{n\in\mathbb N}=1,\frac{1}{2},...,\frac{1}{n}.$ Then, $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}=0,\text{ and}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i}^{n}a_{n}=\infty.$$ Clearly, $0\not=\infty$, therefore $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_{n}\not=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i}^{n}a_{n}$, as you suggested.

---

You mentioned Gödel's IT and said I clearly don't understand what undecidability means; however, it's you who I think doesn't understand, because, while Gödel's original argument certainly contained an unprovability theorem, it fell short of a full undecidability theorem.

Also, I said it is non sequitur since the existence of unprovable propositions within a system does not imply **any** proposition is unprovable within that system, i.e $$\exists P:P\text{ is a proposition}\land P\text{ is unprovable}\nRightarrow\forall P:P\text{ is a proposition}\land P\text{ is unprovable}.$$Then, $P\text{ is a proposition within a given system}\nRightarrow P\text{ is unprovable within that system.}$